# Who is connect and change or upload file through FTP

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, ftp

How to check who is connect through FTP and change or modify files.
I have 50 users and 1 live IP any buddy connect but log show only my live IP.
I can not find local computer name. And user says I am not upload any files.
FTP log shows IP and user but not shows local computer netbios name.
Is it any way to find out who is connect and change files.

Comment: Identifying the OS/FTP server combination would help in reducing the need to make assumptions based on your less than complete description. It sounds like it may be some version of Windows and maybe it's built-in FTP, but that those are only assumptions at best based on your description.

Comment: What ftp server are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a NAT firewall between your users and the FTP server, the FTP server will only be able to log the public address of that NAT firewall.

If the FTP server and the users are on the same local network, but the users are connecting to your public IP address (and the public IP is forwarded to the FTP server) the FTP server still will only see that the clients are coming from the public IP address. Your users would need to connect to the private IP address of the FTP server in order for the FTP server to see their private IP addresses.